# Error assigning a python quaternion

Tags: ros, python, transformations, quaternion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have tried to setup navigation stack to work with the robot from USARSim the same way as in tutorials, but when I start robot_configuration.launch and move_base.launch I get this error related to odometry:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/my_name/ros/usarsim/nodes/my_robot_nav.py", line 127, in <module>
    pub_odom.publish(odom)
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/topics.py", line 677, in publish
    self.impl.publish(data)
...
    buff.write(_struct_7d.pack(_x.pose.pose.position.x, _x.pose.pose.position.y, _x.pose.pose.position.z, _x.pose.pose.orientation.x, _x.pose.pose.orientation.y, _x.pose.pose.orientation.z, _x.pose.pose.orientation.w))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'x'
[usarsim-1] process has died [pid 11052, exit code 1].
log files: /home/hrvoje/.ros/log/1bf16950-642a-11e0-894b-000c29c48bc7/usarsim-1*.log*
```

Section of code that publish odom:

```
odom_quat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,some_odom_theta_data)

odom.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()

odom.header.frame_id = "odom"

odom.pose.pose.position.x = some_odom_x_data
odom.pose.pose.position.y = some_odom_y_data
odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat

odom.child_frame_id = "base_link"
odom.twist.twist.linear.x = 0.0
odom.twist.twist.linear.y = 0.0
odom.twist.twist.linear.z = 0.0
pub_odom.publish(odom)
```

My odometry returns only position and orientation, but not the values for velocity!

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.
hv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9697/error-assigning-a-python-quaternion/) by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-11**:
the problem starts after running move_base.launch, not after robot_configuration.launch

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-11**:
I followed http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup and the section http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom for odometry

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-04-11**:
Which tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would guess that it's this line:

```
odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat
```

odom.pose.pose.orientation is a [quaternion message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Quaternion.html), but odom_quat is a numpy array (which is what transformations.py uses natively)  You need to convert the data type before assigning it.  The numpy array uses index notation, while the message uses .x .y .z and .w

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-21**:
thanks Jack ^^

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-19**:
odom_quat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,some_odom_theta_data), odom.pose.pose.orientation.x = odom_quat[0], odom.pose.pose.orientation.y = odom_quad[1], odom.pose.pose.orientation.z = odom_quad[2], odom.pose.pose.orientation.w = odom_quad[3]

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-15**:
Could you show an example of how to convert the quaternion? My Python skills are quite weak

**Comment by [Jack Sparrow](https://answers.ros.org/users/413/jack-sparrow/) on 2011-04-14**:
Yeah, that's it. Thank you

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-04-22**:
Even simpler via tuple expanding with *: http://answers.ros.org/question/12903/quaternions-with-python?answer=19040#post-id-19040

**Comment by [zephirefaith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27852/zephirefaith/) on 2017-03-08**:
Highly recommend ros_numpy: https://github.com/eric-wieser/ros_numpy, for everyday simple conversions

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I understand well what Tully says, how come is your code not crashing like mine does when you assign odom.pose.pose.position.x = [something]?

In my case, I crash as soon as I try to assign a value as you do in your code:

```
msg = Odometry()
msg.pose.pose.position.x = 0.0
...
pub_odom.publish(msg)
```

always results in:

```
msg.pose.pose.position.x = 0.0
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'
```

From the [documentation](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html), I see that pose.pose.position is a Geometry_msgs/Point message. Should I cast my values in Point and then assign them to position?

Raph

==================

UDPATE

Here is my solution:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
...
msg = Odometry()
msg.pose.pose.position = Point(x,y,0.0)
...
pub_odom.publish(msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-24**:
Thanks. Feel free to vote the answer up ^^

**Comment by [Charles](https://answers.ros.org/users/333/charles/) on 2011-04-23**:
Thanks. I met the same problem.